# Upload file bigger than php.ini's "upload_max_filesize" and "post_max_size" with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, xmlhttprequest, form-data

The following code is a very simple self-hosted file transfer service.
It works for files smaller than 100 MB.

How to make this work for 1 GB files or more? (which might exceed php.ini's `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`)

**More generally, how can we do a `POST` `XMLHttpRequest` file upload (with a file appended to a `FormData` object), with a file bigger than the server's RAM?**

Is there a way to to do the XHR upload by chunks, and if so, how?

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $localfname = $_POST['fname'];
    $data = file_get_contents($_FILES['data']['tmp_name']);
    $fname = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {  
        $fname .= '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'[rand(0, 35)];  
    }     
    $trimmedfname = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', basename($localfname));
    $file = fopen('files/' . $fname . '_' . $trimmedfname, 'w');
    fwrite($file, $data);
    fclose($file);
    $link = 'files/' . $fname . '_' . $trimmedfname;
    echo 'link: <div id="link"><a href="' . $link . '">' . $link . '</a></div>';
    die();
}    
?>
<body>
<div id="container" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: #eee; padding: 1em;">drag and drop your file here!</div>
<script>
var $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
var readfiles = files => {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('fname', files[0].name);
    formData.append('data', files[0]);
    $("#container").innerHTML = 'beginning ulpoad... progress: ';
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '');
    xhr.onload = () => {
        $("#container").innerHTML =  xhr.responseText;
    };
    xhr.upload.onprogress = (event) => {
        if (event.lengthComputable) {
            $("#container").innerHTML = 'ulpoading... progress: ' + (event.loaded / event.total * 100 | 0) + '%<br>';
        }
    };
    xhr.send(formData);
}
document.body.ondragover = () => { $("#container").innerHTML = 'drop your file here...'; return false; };
document.body.ondrop = (e) => { e.preventDefault(); readfiles(e.dataTransfer.files); };
</script>
</body
```

Comment: Those limits are hard limits at the server level, basically kill switches, so I don't think you can bypass them. I'm pretty certain that files aren't stored in memory, however, and will always be backed by files. The only way to beat the system, short of changing the values, at least that comes to my mind, is to performing chunking on the data.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisHaas, yes this is my question (I will edit to emphasize this): how to chunk such a XHR request?

Comment: I’ve seen mentions that `fetch` might be able to do this, but also that it was buggy. Otherwise I’ve only seen people using libraries such as Flow.js or plupload to do this.

Comment: @MahirZukic You mean voting without explanation. It is definitly allowed and even appreciated (voting is important), though explained voting is perceived as even more helpful. But anonymous voting is not flaggable as violation of code of conduct.... Using certain expressions (even obfuscated)  to describe anonymous voters however is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to chunk such a XHR request?

True, chunking a file upload involves breaking down the file into smaller parts (chunks), sending each chunk separately, and then reassembling these parts on the server.

```
Client Browser                     Server
    |                                |
    |--- Upload Chunk 1 -----------> |
    |                                |--- Append Chunk
    |--- Upload Chunk 2 -----------> |
    |                                |--- Append Chunk
    |                                |
    |--- Upload Last Chunk --------> |
    |                                |--- Assemble Chunks
    |<-- Return Link to Uploaded File|
```

That would allow you to bypass the [`upload_max_filesize`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) and [`post_max_size`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) limits in `php.ini` because each chunk can be kept small enough to fit within these limits. But you need to modify both the client-side and server-side code to handle chunked uploads.

On the client-side, modify your JavaScript to slice the file into chunks and upload each piece sequentially (simplified example of a [more complex process](https://github.com/syncfusion/ej2-javascript-ui-controls/blob/878cdef10526b4bd93bded172b0dd58a683bee08/controls/inputs/src/uploader/uploader.ts)):

```js
function uploadChunk(file, start, chunkSize, totalChunks) {
    var end = start + chunkSize;
    var chunk = file.slice(start, end);
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('fname', file.name);
    formData.append('data', chunk);
    formData.append('chunkIndex', Math.floor(start / chunkSize)); // Current chunk
    formData.append('totalChunks', totalChunks);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', '', true);
        xhr.onload = function() {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                resolve();
            } else {
                reject(new Error('Upload failed with status: ' + xhr.status));
            }
        };
        xhr.send(formData);
    });
}

function chunkedUpload(file) {
    const CHUNK_SIZE = 1 * 1024 * 1024; // 1MB chunk size
    const totalChunks = Math.ceil(file.size / CHUNK_SIZE);

    let promise = Promise.resolve();

    for (let start = 0; start < file.size; start += CHUNK_SIZE) {
        promise = promise.then(() => uploadChunk(file, start, CHUNK_SIZE, totalChunks));
    }

    promise.then(() => {
        console.log('All chunks uploaded successfully.');
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error uploading chunks: ', error);
    });
}
```

The JavaScript function `chunkedUpload(file)` should be triggered with the file you want to upload. You can modify your drag and drop or file input listeners to use this function.

On the server side, modify your PHP script to handle chunked uploads. The script needs to append each chunk to a temporary file. Once all chunks have been received, it can then process the file as needed.
As a basic example (For a production environment, you should include error handling, security checks, and possibly support for concurrent uploads):

```php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $chunkIndex = $_POST['chunkIndex'];
    $totalChunks = $_POST['totalChunks'];
    $localfname = $_POST['fname'];
    $chunkData = file_get_contents($_FILES['data']['tmp_name']);
    
    // Create a unique temporary file name based on the original file name.
    $tempDir = sys_get_temp_dir();
    $tempFilePath = $tempDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'chunk_' . md5($localfname);

    // Append the current chunk to the temporary file.
    file_put_contents($tempFilePath, $chunkData, FILE_APPEND);

    // If this is the last chunk, process the file.
    if ($chunkIndex + 1 == $totalChunks) {
        // Move/rename the temporary file to its final destination, etc.
        // For example:
        $finalFilePath = 'files/' . uniqid() . '_' . basename($localfname);
        rename($tempFilePath, $finalFilePath);
        
        echo 'File uploaded successfully. Access it <a href="' . $finalFilePath . '">here</a>.';
    } else {
        echo 'Chunk ' . ($chunkIndex + 1) . ' of ' . $totalChunks . ' uploaded successfully.';
    }
    exit;
}
```

---

> How would you call the JS code?
> Something like `document.body.ondrop = (e) => { e.preventDefault(); chunkedUpload(e.dataTransfer.files[0]); };`?
> Or would you call it another way?

Yes, your approach to calling the `chunkedUpload` function should work.
When a user drops a file onto the designated area, the event listener prevents the default action (which could be opening the file or navigating to it), retrieves the file from the `dataTransfer` object, and then passes this file to the `chunkedUpload` function for processing.

You can add some additional steps, to make sure a smooth user experience (a bit as in [this example](https://gist.github.com/geraintluff/11367f19fc4cb42c2d77#file-index-html-L80)):

```js
document.body.ondragover = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Optionally, add some visual feedback for the user to indicate the drop target
    document.getElementById('container').style.backgroundColor = '#f0f0f0';
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = 'Drop your file here...';
};

document.body.ondragleave = (e) => {
    // Revert visual feedback when the file leaves the drop target area
    document.getElementById('container').style.backgroundColor = '#eee';
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = 'Drag and drop your file here!';
};

document.body.ondrop = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Reset visual feedback once the file is dropped
    document.getElementById('container').style.backgroundColor = '#eee';
    // Clear the previous message
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = 'Beginning upload...';

    // Start the chunked upload process for the first file
    if (e.dataTransfer.files.length > 0) {
        chunkedUpload(e.dataTransfer.files[0]);
    } else {
        // If no files were dropped, inform the user
        document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = 'No file detected. Please try again.';
    }
};
```

That would provide feedback during the drag-over and drag-leave events, making it clearer to users where they should drop their files. Once the file is dropped, it proceeds with the upload and gives an immediate visual response that something is happening.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems like the good way to do it! How would you call the JS code? Something like `document.body.ondrop = (e) => { e.preventDefault(); chunkedUpload(e.dataTransfer.files[0]); };`? Or would you call it another way?

Comment: @Basj Yes (to your proposed code). I have edited the answer to include an example.